# grid panel toolbar failed rendering textfield

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I want to add textfield into tbar in Grid panel, but it does not work.

And I tried with button then it works..

This code is not working, the error message say, **TypeError: g.el is null**

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
...
tbar : [
  {
     xtype : 'textfield',
     name : 'test'
  }
]
});
```

But this code is working,

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
...
tbar : [
  {
     xtype : 'button',
     text : 'keyword'
  }
]
});
```

Anybody know, why it happened?

I found,

it *renderTo : 'tableID'*, but I changed to **renderTo : Ext.getBody()**

then it works. but I want to put the grid into specific html element, how should I do?

[Edit]

I want to insert to #listTable,

```
<div id="wrap">
    <table id="listTable"></table>
</div>
```

I just tried to 'wrap' then it works,

So I tried, **renderTo : 'wrap > listTable'**

but it does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works without any error in 4.1.3. It may be a bug in your version? You can test it in one of the [API demo](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) boxes. Just copy paste it. The `tbar` prop is ah shorthand for a `dockedItem` that get applied to `top`. A passed array get automatically inserted into a `toolbar`. Nothing more happends. So it must work

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    tbar: [
      {
         xtype : 'textfield',
         name : 'test'
      }
    ],
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

**Edit**

**[renderTo](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-renderTo)** requires a valid `id`, a HTML Element or **[Ext.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I replace with your code and I found what was the problem, it was renderTo. but still I couldn't find the solution, could you review my edited question again please?

Comment: @Expertwannabe don't use renderTo. Place it directly into the items array of the owner component

Comment: sorry for asking again, but still I don't get it. could you explain a little more detail please?

Comment: @Expertwannabe can you post a example where you want to inster the grid? Or is it a plain html element?

Comment: @Expertwannabe
you can't render into a table, it need to be a div!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me on ExtJS 4.1, though I usually initialize components within an initComponent function (though I don't see why it shouldn't work as you do it). So this would be something like:

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.dockedItems = [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [ {xtype:'textfield', name:'test', value:'test'} ]
    }];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do this within initComponents.

Comment: You are right, you don't, and I do that for other reasons. In any case - the code from the question above should work either way.